# How do the various classifications of $p$-divisible groups relate?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, big-list

There are several dozen 'classification' theorems of various notions of $p$-divisible groups in terms of crystals (where 'crystal' can seemingly mean various things), thanks to theorems of Dieudonné, Grothendieck, Messing, Mazur, Manin, Bertelot, Ogus, Cartier, Fontaine, A. de Jong, Breuil, Kisin, Scholze, Weinstein, and likely many others. As a newcomer I have no idea how to untangle all this mess. Could someone give me a clear overview on the following?

> How do all these different classification theorems relate? Do I understand correctly that they are all just different special cases of an envisaged classification of $p$-divisible groups over an arbitrary base?
>
> What is it that motivates people? Messing showed that $p$-divisible groups over arbitrary base schemes with $p$ nilpotent are in correspondence with certain crystals. Aren't we close to done then?

I am completely OK with skipping technicalities. I just want to get an overview of what is going on.

Comment: The first thing to understand is the classification of $p$-divisible groups over a perfect field of characteristic $p$ $k$ in terms of Dieudonne modules over the ring of Witt vectors $W(k)$. Everything else is in some sense just trying to generalise this (very nice) theory to more general bases.

Comment: @user45878 What would be the next step? Is it correct to say that there isn't a general classification for all bases, and that everything beyond the work of Grothendieck--Messing, which covers all bases with p nilpotent, is to drop the nilpotence condition? Or is there more to the story?

Comment: This might be a bit late, but anyway: A general classification seems quite tough, as far as I can see. As far as I know, Messing mostly defines the construction. It was De Jong later on, who made some statements about when the functor associating a crystal to a $p$-div. group is fully faithful. The latest result, although it might be not necessary for what you have in mind, is prismatic Dieudonne theory, which is a further generalisation of the former.